# Firebase Email/PW Auth Won't Register

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a simple app that allows users to register to Firebase through the Auth method. Here's my code:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private EditText tbemail;
private EditText tbpassword;

private Button btnCreate;
private Button btnSignIn;

private String str_email;
private String str_password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    //GUI DECLARATIONS
    tbemail     =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tb_email);
    tbpassword  =   (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tb_password);

    btnCreate   =   (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_create);
    btnSignIn   =   (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signin);



    btnCreate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            str_email       =   tbemail.getText().toString().trim();
            str_password    =   tbpassword.getText().toString().trim();

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(str_email, str_password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //TASK SUCCESSFUL
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "User Created Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        //TASK ERROR
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "There was an error. Please Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });





    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent signInIntent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(signInIntent);
        }
    });




}
}
```

But when I tried inputing the textboxes and hitting "Create User" it gives me the "Sorry there was an error..." toast suggesting it failed in registering the new user. Logcat says `E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb2b31680`
Any ways to fix this?

## Update

I already connected my project to firebase; just in case you're wondering.

## Update 2

It suddenly showed me this in logcat `Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.` Just now. (I didn't do anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this in your fire base console Authentication -> **Sign-In-Method** -> **Email/Password** is enable.

In the Firebase console, open the Authentication section.

On the Sign in method tab, enable the Email/password sign-in method and click Save.

[image]

you must add Internet permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The possible **reasons** for **failure** are:

- The email address is malformed
- Sign-in by email/password is disabled
- The user account corresponding to the email does not exist or has been deleted
- The user account corresponding to the email has been disabled
- The password is wrong
- The user's token is not valid

Comment: I already tried both sir, but it didn't work. Logcat: `E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae60f860` I think something's really going on in that buffer error. I really don't know what is it.

Comment: @DranrebBenedicto are you testing in real device and real email address.

Comment: @DranrebBenedicto please check my edit answer for possible reason for failure.

Comment: I tried testing in Virtual and Real device; tried testing fake and real email; still didn't work sir.

Comment: you can check your gradle file 'compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0''

Comment: Mine says `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'` is this it ?

Comment: use latest version and clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Forgive me for being so newbie of this sir, how do I this sir: `use latest version`

Comment: you can read more this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth